# Using async websockets in Rust with tokio, rmp-serde and varint encoding

Tags: rust, asynchronous, websocket

This is my first attempt at a real life app in Rust. I would mostly like to know if I am writing idiomatic Rust code, coming from Java and Python. I'll appreciate any pointers to improvements, though.

The code uses `tokio_tungstenite` to receive messages from a websocket server asynchronously. The connection as well as the handshake and a mandatory subscription call happen in a synchronous manner before.
Once subscribed, the websocket server will start sending `varint` encoded `messagepack` messages. I could not find a decent varint crate that suited my purposes, so I wrote I small module myself. Furthermore, I had to write another module that handles messagepack timestamp serialization and deserialization since the `rmp-serde` crate does not provide this functionality and the incoming messagepack messages contain messagepack style timestamps.

The websocket server occasionally sends a ping message amongst the actual messages. In this case, a custom pong message is being sent to the server containing the contents of the ping itself.
I am using channels to notify the pong sender task to send back the pong from within the loop that waits for new messages to come in.

**Specific questions:**

1 - The `RealResponse` struct represents one response message, however, only the `data` field has meaningful value. All other fields are either {}, null or []. Let me know if I gave those fields the correct type (like `Option<()>`).

2 - I have many constructs like

```
let a = match x {
   Ok(a) => a,
   Err(e) => handle error meaningfully
}
```

for which I would like to know if I could write them in a more concise way.

**Code structure:**

```
   |-- Cargo.toml
   |-- src
         |-- mp_ext
         |   |-- mod.rs
         |
         |-- varint
         |   |-- mod.rs
         |
         |-- lib.rs
         |-- main.rs
```

Cargo.toml looks like this:

```
[package]
name = "myproject"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
tokio = {version = "1.34", features = ["full"]}
tokio-tungstenite = {version = "0.20", features = ["native-tls"]}
futures-util = "0.3"
futures-sink = "0.3"
futures-channel = "0.3"
rmp-serde = "1.1.2"
serde = { version = "1", features = ["derive"] }
serde_bytes = "0.11"
```

**Code:**

main.rs:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    myproject::start().await;
}
```

lib.rs:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::vec;

use futures_channel::mpsc;
use futures_util::{
    stream::{SplitSink, SplitStream},
    SinkExt, StreamExt,
};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::process;
use tokio::net::TcpStream;
use tokio_tungstenite::{
    connect_async,
    tungstenite::{self, handshake, http, Message},
    MaybeTlsStream, WebSocketStream,
};

mod mp_ext;
mod varint;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize)]
struct SubscribeRequest {
    r#type: u8,
    empty: HashMap<(), ()>,
    invocation_id: &'static str,
    endpoint: &'static str,
    identifiers: [Vec<&'static str>; 1],
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
struct RealData {
    push_identifier: String,
    data1: f64,
    data2: f64,
    data3: f64,
    data4: f64,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "mp_ext::deserialize_mp_timestamp_sec")]
    data1_date_time: u64,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "mp_ext::deserialize_mp_timestamp_sec")]
    data2_date_time: u64,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "mp_ext::deserialize_mp_timestamp_sec")]
    data3_date_time: u64,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "mp_ext::deserialize_mp_timestamp_sec")]
    data4_date_time: u64,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Deserialize)]
struct RealResponse {
    r#type: u8,
    empty: HashMap<(), ()>,
    unknown: Option<()>,
    endpoint: String,
    data: [[RealData; 1]; 1],
    unknown2: [(); 0],
}

pub async fn start() {
    let request = http::Request::builder()
        .uri("wss://some_domain.com/real")
        .header("Host", "some_domain.com")
        .header("Origin", "https://www.some_domain.com")
        .header("Connection", "Upgrade")
        .header("Upgrade", "websocket")
        .header("pragma", "no-cache")
        .header("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
        .header("Sec-WebSocket-Version", 13)
        .header("Sec-WebSocket-Extensions", "permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits")
        .header("Sec-WebSocket-Key", handshake::client::generate_key())
        .header("User-Agent", "some_agent")
        .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
        .header("Accept-Language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.7")
        .body(())
        .unwrap();

    // connect and split into sender and receiver
    let (ws_stream, _) = connect_async(request).await.unwrap();
    let (mut sender_ws, mut receiver_ws) = ws_stream.split();

    // send handshake and subscription request
    websocket_handshake(&mut sender_ws, &mut receiver_ws).await;
    subscribe(&mut sender_ws, &mut receiver_ws).await;

    // this channel is used to send pongs to the server
    let (sender_pong, receiver_pong) = mpsc::unbounded::<Vec<u8>>();

    // spawn the pong handler
    tokio::spawn(spawn_pong_handler(receiver_pong, sender_ws));

    // receive messages until connection has been closed
    loop {
        let response = receiver_ws.next().await;

        if response.is_none() {
            println!("Connection has been closed.");
            break;
        }

        // spawn a new task for every good response
        tokio::spawn(process_incoming_messages(
            response.unwrap(),
            sender_pong.clone(),
        ));
    }
}

async fn websocket_handshake(
    sender_ws: &mut SplitSink<WebSocketStream<MaybeTlsStream<TcpStream>>, Message>,
    receiver_ws: &mut SplitStream<WebSocketStream<MaybeTlsStream<TcpStream>>>,
) {
    sender_ws
        .send(Message::Text(
            "{\"protocol\":\"messagepack\",\"version\":1}\x1e".to_string(),
        ))
        .await
        .expect("Unable to send handshake.");
    let response = receiver_ws
        .next()
        .await
        .expect("Unable to read handshake.")
        .expect("Unable to read handshake.");

    if let Ok("{}\x1e") = response.to_text() {
        println!("WebSocket handshake has been successfully completed.");
    } else {
        eprintln!("Bad handshake. Aborting!");
        process::exit(1);
    }
}

async fn subscribe(
    sender_ws: &mut SplitSink<WebSocketStream<MaybeTlsStream<TcpStream>>, Message>,
    receiver_ws: &mut SplitStream<WebSocketStream<MaybeTlsStream<TcpStream>>>,
) {
    // send subscribe message for given IDs
    let subscribe_request = SubscribeRequest {
        r#type: 1,
        empty: HashMap::new(),
        invocation_id: "0",
        endpoint: "Subscribe",
        identifiers: [vec!["IDENTIFIER"]],
    };

    let subscribe_request = match rmp_serde::to_vec(&subscribe_request) {
        Ok(subscribe_request) => subscribe_request,
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Error serializing subscribe request: {}.", e);
            process::exit(1);
        }
    };
    let subscribe_request = varint::encode(subscribe_request);
    sender_ws
        .send(Message::Binary(subscribe_request))
        .await
        .expect("Unable to send subscribe message.");

    let response = receiver_ws
        .next()
        .await
        .expect("Unable to read subscribe response.")
        .expect("Unable to read subscribe response.")
        .into_data();
    if response == vec![7, 149, 3, 128, 161, 48, 3, 192] {
        println!("Successfully sent subscription request.");
    } else {
        eprintln!("Bad subscription response. Aborting!");
        process::exit(1);
    }
}

async fn spawn_pong_handler(
    mut receiver_pong: mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<Vec<u8>>,
    mut sender_ws: SplitSink<WebSocketStream<MaybeTlsStream<TcpStream>>, Message>,
) {
    // The ping/pong handler
    loop {
        // For the pong we need to send the same data as the ping.
        let ping = match receiver_pong.next().await {
            Some(ping) => ping,
            // connection has been closed
            None => continue,
        };

        match sender_ws.send(Message::Binary(varint::encode(ping))).await {
            Ok(_) => println!("Pong "),
            Err(e) => eprintln!("Unable to send pong: {}.", e),
        };
    }
}

async fn process_incoming_messages(
    response: Result<Message, tungstenite::Error>,
    sender_pong: mpsc::UnboundedSender<Vec<u8>>,
) {
    // decode the responses (data or ping)
    let response = match response {
        Ok(res) => res,
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Unable to read socket: {}.", e);
            process::exit(1);
        }
    };
    let response = match varint::decode(&response.into_data()) {
        Ok(response) => response,
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Error decoding message: {}.", e);
            return;
        }
    };

    for message in response {
        match message.len() {
            2 => process_ping(&sender_pong, message),
            _ => process_message(message),
        }
    }
}

fn process_ping(sender_pong: &mpsc::UnboundedSender<Vec<u8>>, message: Vec<u8>) {
    println!("Ping!");
    if let Err(e) = sender_pong.unbounded_send(message) {
        eprintln!("Unable to send ping: {}.", e);
    }
}

fn process_message(message: Vec<u8>) {
    // the actual handler
    let response = match rmp_serde::from_slice::<RealResponse>(&message) {
        Ok(res) => res,
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Error decoding message: {}.", e);
            return;
        }
    };
    println!("{:?}", response.data[0][0]);
    //todo!();
}
```

mod.rs in varint module (no need to check the logic):

```
pub fn encode(byte_data: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut varint_length = byte_data.len();
    let mut varint_bytes = Vec::new();
    while varint_length > 0 {
        let mut byte = (varint_length & 127) as u8;
        varint_length >>= 7;
        if varint_length > 0 {
            byte |= 128;
        }
        varint_bytes.push(byte);
    }
    varint_bytes.extend(byte_data);
    varint_bytes
}

pub fn decode(byte_data: &[u8]) -> Result<Vec<Vec<u8>>, &'static str> {
    let mut decoded_messages: Vec<Vec<u8>> = Vec::new();
    let mut index: usize = 0;

    while index < byte_data.len() {
        let mut varint_bytes: usize = 0;
        let mut varint_length: usize = 0;

        loop {
            let current_byte = byte_data[index + varint_bytes];
            varint_length |= ((current_byte & 127) as usize) << (varint_bytes * 7);
            varint_bytes += 1;
            if current_byte & 128 == 0 {
                break;
            }
        }

        if varint_length > 0x7FFFFFFF {
            return Err("Messages bigger than 2GB are not supported.");
        }

        index += varint_bytes;

        if byte_data.len() >= index + varint_length {
            let message = byte_data[index..index + varint_length].to_vec();
            decoded_messages.push(message);
            index += varint_length;
        } else {
            return Err("Incomplete message.");
        }
    }

    Ok(decoded_messages)
}
```

mod.rs in mp_ext (no need to check the logic of the timestamp conversions):

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer, Serialize, Serializer};
use serde_bytes::ByteBuf;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename = "_ExtStruct")]
struct ExtStruct((i8, ByteBuf));

#[allow(dead_code)]
pub fn serialize_mp_timestamp<S>(timestamp: &Timestamp, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
where
    S: Serializer,
{
    ExtStruct((-1, timestamp.as_mp_bytes())).serialize(serializer)
}

pub fn deserialize_mp_timestamp<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Timestamp, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let ExtStruct((ext_type, buf)) = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    if ext_type != -1 {
        return Err(serde::de::Error::custom("Invalid extension type (!=-1)"));
    }

    Timestamp::from_mp_bytes(buf).map_err(serde::de::Error::custom)
}

pub fn deserialize_mp_timestamp_sec<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<u64, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    deserialize_mp_timestamp(deserializer).map(|ts| ts.seconds)
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Hash)]
pub struct Timestamp {
    pub seconds: u64,
    pub nanoseconds: u32,
}

impl Timestamp {
    fn from_mp_bytes(bytes: ByteBuf) -> Result<Self, &'static str> {
        let bytes = bytes.into_vec();
        let len = bytes.len();
        let (seconds, nanoseconds) = match len {
            4 => (u32::from_be_bytes(bytes.try_into().unwrap()) as u64, 0),
            8 => {
                let data64 = u64::from_be_bytes(bytes.try_into().unwrap());
                (data64 & 0x00000003ffffffff, (data64 >> 34) as u32)
            }
            12 => {
                let (nanoseconds_bytes, seconds_bytes) = bytes.split_at(4);
                (
                    u64::from_be_bytes(seconds_bytes.try_into().unwrap()),
                    u32::from_be_bytes(nanoseconds_bytes.try_into().unwrap()),
                )
            }
            _ => return Err("Timestamp can only be created from 32, 64, or 96-bit byte objects"),
        };

        Ok(Self {
            seconds,
            nanoseconds,
        })
    }

    fn as_mp_bytes(&self) -> ByteBuf {
        if (self.seconds >> 34) == 0 {
            let mut data = [0u8; 8];

            let data64 = (self.nanoseconds as u64) << 34 | self.seconds;

            if data64 & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000 == 0 {
                data[..4].copy_from_slice(&data64.to_be_bytes()[..4]);
                data[4..].fill(0);
            } else {
                data.copy_from_slice(&data64.to_be_bytes());
            }

            return ByteBuf::from(data);
        }

        let mut data = [0u8; 12];
        data[..4].copy_from_slice(&self.nanoseconds.to_be_bytes());
        data[4..].copy_from_slice(&self.seconds.to_be_bytes());

        ByteBuf::from(data)
    }
}
```

[ I did not manage to find a decent example online for neither, tokio_tungstenite nor messagepack style timestamps. If anything, this code might help others struggling with those crates. ]

Answer (score 3):

First of all, kudos to using `cargo fmt`. It makes for an easy read.

## Use clippy

If you're not doing it yet, I suggest you use `cargo clippy` with the following options:

- `-W clippy::pedantic`
- `-W clippy::nursery`
- `-W clippy::unwrap_used`
- `-W clippy::cargo`

It will provide you with a stricter set of lints, though you need to be aware that it also may produce false-positives in rare cases.

## `RealResponse`

Regarding `RealResponse`, why does it contain the other fields if they are unused? Serde will skip unknown fields by default, so you can just leave unused fields out of the struct.

## Repeating `match` statements

If the repeated match statements bother you, you may want to have a look at `unwrap_or()` and `unwrap_or_else()` respectively. With the options above, clippy may already suggest those to you in appropriate cases.
That being said, there is generally nothing wrong with the match syntax as you use it - I'd rather consider this a matter of taste.

## Long types

The types `SplitSink<WebSocketStream<MaybeTlsStream<TcpStream>>, Message>` and `SplitStream<WebSocketStream<MaybeTlsStream<TcpStream>>>`  are rather long. You may want to consider to type-alias those for abbreviation.

Comment: Thank you! To be clear, the JSON/messagepack response does contain the fields in the RealResponse struct but they have the default values {}, null, "" or []. I just tried leaving out the fields in the struct, only keeping the data field, but this fails.

Comment: Regarding the repeating match statement, the solution is called "let ... else"! That way I can't access the error in Err in a Result anymore, but it't fine for me. Clippy::nursery pointed me at that!

Comment: That directly contraticts your premise *handle error meaningfully*